# bootloader install faield

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, reboot

I have tried to install Ubuntu 20.4 and I already have windows 10.

During installation, I choose install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 and these error appear :

error1
[image: error2]

and after that , it appears :
[image: error1]

I also have enough unallocated storage for ubuntu (more than 200 GB)

My HDD style was MBR, I also tried in GPT style. But I saw the same error. I again changed it to MBR.

What should I do now?
Thank you so much.

Comment: In UEFI or Legacy? If UEFI, what is the size of `/boot/efi`? How much empty space it have?

Comment: It is legacy. thank you.

Comment: You mean my unallocated spase?

Comment: If drive is gpt partitioned (which I recommend), you need either an ESP - efi system partition(300 to 500MB FAT32 with boot flag) for UEFI boot or a bios_grub partition (1 or 2MB unformatted with bios_grub flag) for BIOS boot.  Only use MBR, if installing Windows in BIOS boot mode as that is required by Windows. Make sure Windows fast startup is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Could you explain more what should I do? I mean how should I build an  ESP-efi system partition or even how to bios_grub partition.  @oldfred

Comment: If UEFI system better to use UEFI. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation
You can also use gparted but must change default partitioning first.
Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. gparted & fdisk instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive The bios_grub is selected with right click in gparted.

Comment: I know it is too late, but I just wanted to say thank you.